# How to edit mesh design normally after applying shapekeys?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, edit-mode, shape-keys

So I created some shapekeys for my character, however, I noticed I need to edit the mesh to form a new design.

When I try to edit the mesh, it still apply's to my last shapekey I created, hence when I return to object mode the edit disappears?

Is it possible to edit the design of a character after you've created shapekeys?

Or would I need to delete all my shapekeys to fix the mesh?

Comment: of course you can, it will be easier if you select the basis shapekey, but the changes you'll make may affect the other shapekeys

Comment: oh so only basis works, but any others would ruin the shapekey

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about moving some vertices, edit the *Basis* shapekey, which is your reference shape. Of course it will affect the other shapekeys as they take the basis shapekey into account. If you edit Key 1 or Key 2 it won't affect the basis, only the selected shapekey. If you're talking about just adding new vertices, you can do it in another shapekey than the basis one as it won't change its shape, only its topology.

If it makes things complicated, depending on your project, it may be better to use bones.